# display date/time on website base on user computer time in different country

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I am developing a chatting messenger of website application. For my concept, I avoid to use timezone.

When a user post a message, I use php to get my current server date/time and save it onto database.

To display the time of all messages to the user, I just need find out the different between server time and user's system time. Let's say the different is 3 hours, i just need use mysql to retrieve recorded server time from database then add it with 3, eg : $message-time-display = $server-time-of-message-posted + $different.

For this solution, although the user's computer time may be incorrect, it will not effect the time records that saved on my database. And it will display the correct time when the users have corrected their computer's time. Is this solution is reliable? If so, why there is none of people doing this? Why so many people are using GMT or timezone thingy? Maybe I miss some important issue?

Comment: You can't do this with PHP due to step 2.  PHP has no way of knowing what the time is on the user's computer.  You'd need Java to grab that.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about this. No worry, i can use javascript to grab it then pass javascript variable to php variable by $local_time = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> document.write(local_time); </script>";

Comment: Hum, that will only put the string "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> document.write(local_time); </script>"; in the var $local_time. To send the data back to PHP you will need to use some form of AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to use AJAX, PHP gets parsed and served up before Java ever runs on the client machine.

Comment: i didn't use ajax, i use jQuery.get("chktimedif.php?usertime="+usertime, function(data) {
  }); to pass the javascript variable to php, so that the php can do the math calculation between server time and client time by using mysql SELECT TIMEDIFF ('$usertime','$servertime')

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix is not to show the exact time, rather the time elapsed. Ex: 2 minutes ago

And then...

Since you know the elapsed time you can substract that from the user's current time.
You can get the user current time with javascript.

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand your sentences... why not to show exact time?

Comment: after much thinking, now i understand what are you talking about. Anyway this is not what want, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an app that will only ever be on one server then it's ok to store time as your local server time.  If your application will be deployed in many locations around the globe, then it makes better sense to store all times as [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

To my mind, user-provided times should be translated from user's timezone to UTC (or your server's timezone if it's your personal app) before being stored and should be translated back to the user's timezone when displayed.

So in your case, it should go something like this:

1. user action -> store UTC time in database
2. another user action -> compare current UTC time to stored UTC time and display difference.

If you're displaying timestamps, it should go like this:

1. user action -> store UTC time in database
2. user access -> retrieve stored UTC time and translate it to user's timezone. Display.

Comment: why need to "translate it to user's timezone" ? I though I just need to I display the $result = $recorded_server_time + $different_between_local_and_server_time?

Comment: @zac1987: if you're displaying elapsed time, use the first example.  If you're displaying the time an action was completed, use the second example.  You don't have to display timestamps in the local time, but users appreciate it.

Comment: @dnagirl, what is mean by elapsed time? $elapsed_time = $server_time - $local_time? The elapsed time is the different hours between server time and local time? I though I can display the time an action was completed by showing the $result = $recorded_server_time + or - $elapsed_time?

Comment: @zac1987: `$elapsed = $now - $then;` Don't mix your server and user time systems.  Do the calculation all in one system.  Either `$elapsed= $usernow - $userthen;` OR `$elapsed= $servernow - $serverthen;` Either expression will give the same answer just like 6-2=4 and 12-8=4.

Comment: @dnagirl, if i use your concept, then i need to translate the stored server time into user's timezone. For my concept, I avoid timezone translation, first I find out the different between server time and user's system time. Let's say the different is 3 hour, I store digit "3" at the field of "different" in database. So my database has 2 fields - "server_time" and "different". So although the user's system time is incorrect, it won't affect my database records. When I want display the times of current message and previous message, I...

Comment: I use php to get user's system current time again, then compare it to server current time again to get the different. If the current different is 5 hours, but the previous stored different is 3 hours only, then mysql will update previous stored different to 5. So the times of older message will be the result of previous $server_time - 5, and the time of current message will be the reslut of current $server_time - 5.

Comment: why the current different is 5 but previous different is 3? because maybe the user has updated his computer time to ahead 2 hours or maybe the world timezone time on his area is updated to ahead 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work as long as the user has the time set correctly. That is the only problem actually. Why do you think no one is doing it ? I guess most of them do and only the lazy ones relies on GMT/EST times.

Hint: I saw the user time sent in tracking codes such as google's analytics javascript, probably for computing the difference you are taking about ;)