# How to get the user's system clock time to display in a web application?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timestamp, clock

I noticed when I accessed my gmail account after I changed my system clock on windows 7 from Pacific to Eastern time, the timestamp in all my emails went up by 3 hours.

Is there a way I can obtain a user's system clock time so I can display it in a web application?

I mainly use php for writing web apps but I did not see and `$_SESSION` variables that contain that information.

Comment: Easiest way to get the user's local time is to use javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [display date/time on website base on user computer time in different country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600117/display-date-time-on-website-base-on-user-computer-time-in-different-country)
From that reference, `$local_time = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> document.write(local_time); </script>"; ` is an easy way to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't run on the client but on the server, so if you want to do this you can use some JavaScript.

```
function set_time() {

var d = new Date();
var c_hour = d.getHours();
var c_min = d.getMinutes();
var c_sec = d.getSeconds();
var t = c_hour + ":" + c_min + ":" + c_sec;
return t;
```

}

Comment: While it's easier with javascript you could always find the user's location by ip address and figure out their time zone and calculate their local time.

Comment: @Rob technically that's also not safe :) what if user pc's time is not synced with his/her time zone? :)